# MSP430 ports access

Tags: c, ports, msp430

I'm working on a project using msp430. How can i read the value received by a specific port and assign it to a variable? Like P1.5 ? I already set P1DIR to input.
I did:

```
data = (P1IN & SDA_TMP); // Where SDA_TMP is a defined prep
```

Comment: What is the value of SDA_TMP?

Comment: What do you mean by "a defined prep"?

Comment: SDA_TMP is : #define SDA_TMP     (0x0020)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

```
const bool data = (P1IN & (1 << 5)) != 0;
```

This uses bitwise and (`&`) to mask out the fifth bit (whose value is `1 << 5`), then does a comparison against zero. The result in `data` will be `true` if bit 5 is set, `false` if it isn't.

See also [this tutorial](http://maxembedded.com/2013/12/io-port-operations-in-msp430/) for more.

Comment: Ok thanks . That's what i was looking for... I'm coding in C, so i'll replace const bool by unsigned char